# WPF Detect ValidationRule Errors

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok this is driving me insane and has to be something simple.  I want to detect if there is any validation in the window before doing a save.  Looking online I see multiple response of this;

```
<TextBox Validation.Error="ValidationError" 
 .... 
</TextBox>
```

That looks like exactly what I want.  Problem is that `Validation.Error` is not a valid option for me; 
[image]

I am running Visual Studio 2013 WPF C#.  Is there some library that I missing?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Provide some code! Usually the data in the window is bound to domain class instance(s), also validation errors currently present in those instance(s). So, rather than exmanining your window you really should examine your bound domain class instance.

Comment: Have a look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: this also does happen to me. Not sure why but normally Visual Studio will hide ***unrecommended*** options by default in intellisense dropdown. Although typing it will compile OK.

Comment: @King King That did it! thanks for help that was way too simple.  If you want put this comment as reply and I will upvote and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Xaphann OK, but it's too simple for an answer (I didn't even know that answers to your problem).